# Why does the scala worksheet in Intellij fail to recognize vars?

Tags: scala, intellij-13

I have a scala worksheet in Intellij that's confusing me. What am I doing wrong?

This works:

[image]

This doesn't:

[image]

Comment: that sounds like an intellij bug, it has been reported multiple times http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL?q=worksheet+var and is fixed  upstream